# On DropDownList Selection, Filter SQL Query with Ajax Partial View, MVC

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm at a loss for where, and the best practice would be to filter the selected value from the dropdownlist. So here goes:

On dropdownlist selection I would like for the selected value to filter the sql query and only show the videos that relate to the ID of the dropdownlist selection.  At the moment it is showing only the first video in the database 10 times. There are 10 videos in the database and I realize because ID = ID they are all showing... I would just like the ones that relate to the selected item in the dropdownlist to show within the partial view.

VIEWMODEL

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ACGteam.ViewModels
{
    public class AthleteVideoViewModel
    {
        public List<AthleteVideoViewModel> AthleteDbList { get; set; }
        public int anAthleteID { get; set; }
        public int AthleteID { get; set; }
        public string AthleteName { get; set; }
        public int AthleteVideoID { get; set; }
        public string AthleteVideo { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AthleteListItems
        {
            get { return new SelectList(AthleteDbList, "AthleteID", "AthleteName"); }
        }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AthleteVideosList
        {
            get { return new SelectList(AthleteDbList, "anAthleteID", "AthleteVideo"); }
        }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ACGteam.Models;
using ACGteam.ViewModels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using ACGteam.Services;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;


namespace ACGteam.Controllers
{
    public class VideosController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult VideoPage()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult VideoPage2016()
        {
            var ddlAthleteSelected = new AthleteVideoViewModel();

            ddlAthleteSelected.AthleteDbList = PopulateAthleteNames();

            return View(ddlAthleteSelected);
        }
        private List<AthleteVideoViewModel> PopulateAthleteNames()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection.GetConnectionString("acgvideodbConnectionString")))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT AthleteID, AthleteName AS Athlete FROM Athlete_Name ORDER BY Athlete";
                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            sda.Fill(ds);

                            var items = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new AthleteVideoViewModel { AthleteID = dataRow.Field<int>("AthleteID"), AthleteName = dataRow.Field<string>("Athlete") }).ToList();

                            return items;
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public PartialViewResult GetAthleteVideo(int AthleteID)
        {

            var vidModels = new AthleteVideoViewModel();
            vidModels.AthleteDbList = PopulateVideosWithAthleteID();
            var vid = vidModels.AthleteDbList.Where(a => a.anAthleteID == AthleteID).FirstOrDefault();

            vidModels.AthleteVideo = vid.AthleteVideo;

            return PartialView("_ShowAthlete", vidModels);
        }

        private List<AthleteVideoViewModel> PopulateVideosWithAthleteID()
        {

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection.GetConnectionString("acgvideodbConnectionString")))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        List<AthleteVideoViewModel> vidmod = new List<AthleteVideoViewModel>();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Athlete_Name.AthleteID AS AthleteID, Athlete_Video.anAthleteID AS anAthleteID, Athlete_Video.AthleteVideo AS AthleteVideo FROM Athlete_Video INNER JOIN Athlete_Name ON Athlete_Name.AthleteID = Athlete_Video.anAthleteID";
                        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        sda.Fill(ds);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                        vidmod = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new AthleteVideoViewModel { AthleteID = dataRow.Field<int>("AthleteID"), anAthleteID = dataRow.Field<int>("anAthleteID"), AthleteVideo = dataRow.Field<string>("AthleteVideo") }).ToList();

                        return vidmod;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MAIN VIEW

```
@model ACGteam.ViewModels.AthleteVideoViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VideosPage2016";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <h2 style="text-align:center">ACG 2015-2016 Competition Season</h2>
        <h2 style="text-align:center"> Athlete Videos </h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin:auto 0; display:block">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AthleteID, Model.AthleteListItems, new { Class = "imgcenter", id = "ddlAthlete" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="partialDiv">
            @Html.Partial("_ShowAthlete")
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#ddlAthlete").on("change", function () {
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "GetAthleteVideo?AthleteID=" + $(this).prop("value"),
                        type: "GET",
                        data: "",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            $("#partialDiv").html(data);
                        },
                        error: function () { alert("error"); }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

PARTIAL VIEW

```
@model ACGteam.ViewModels.AthleteVideoViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_ShowAthlete";
}
<div class="row">
    <div style="display: block; text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <img height="75" width="100" src="/Img/AvantCoeurLogoGirls.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 display-label">
            @Html.DisplayFor(items => items.AthleteName)
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="row">
                    @foreach (var athVid in Model.AthleteDbList)
                {
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 img-responsive">
                            <video style="height:250px; width:250px" controls="controls">
                                <source src="@Html.DisplayFor(vidmod => vidmod.AthleteVideo)" type="video/mp4" />
                            </video>
                            <br />
                            <strong>GroupShow_Candyland</strong>
                        </div>
                }
```

[This is the Query Result from the Method, PopulateVideosWithAthleteID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3T7n.png)

Comment: The problem is in partial view. But before I can provide solution based on assumptions can you answer following question? Can there be only one video for one athlete? Method `PopulateVideosWithAthleteID` populates all the videos from db without filtering them based on `athleteId` Is that intentional? If you can share some sample data from your database that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is possible there may be only one video for one athlete. It's not intentional, I thought this .Where(a => a.anAthleteID == AthleteID) would be doing the filtering for me. If I should filter athleteID in the PopulateVideosWithAthleteID Method that works also. Any light you can shed on this is helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change method `PopulateVideosWithAthleteID` as following.

```
private List<AthleteVideoViewModel> PopulateVideosWithAthleteID(int anAthleteId)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection.GetConnectionString("acgvideodbConnectionString")))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                List<AthleteVideoViewModel> vidmod = new List<AthleteVideoViewModel>();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Athlete_Name.AthleteID AS AthleteID, Athlete_Video.anAthleteID AS anAthleteID, Athlete_Video.AthleteVideo AS AthleteVideo FROM Athlete_Video INNER JOIN Athlete_Name ON Athlete_Name.AthleteID = Athlete_Video.anAthleteID WHERE Athlete_Video.anAthleteID = @anAthleteId";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@anAthleteId", anAthleteId);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                vidmod = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new AthleteVideoViewModel { AthleteID = dataRow.Field<int>("AthleteID"), anAthleteID = dataRow.Field<int>("anAthleteID"), AthleteVideo = dataRow.Field<string>("AthleteVideo") }).ToList();

                return vidmod;
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this method will return the list of videos for the provided athleteId.

Call this method as following from the controller action to populate the property of the model class.

```
public PartialViewResult GetAthleteVideo(int AthleteID)
{
    var vidModels = new AthleteVideoViewModel();
    vidModels.AthleteDbList = PopulateVideosWithAthleteID(AthleteID);
    return PartialView("_ShowAthlete", vidModels);
}
```

The PartialView code changes as following.

```
@model ACGteam.ViewModels.AthleteVideoViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_ShowAthlete";
}
<div class="row">
    <div style="display: block; text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <img height="75" width="100" src="/Img/AvantCoeurLogoGirls.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 display-label">
            @Html.DisplayFor(items => items.AthleteName)
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="row">
                @{
                    for (var count = 0; count < Model.AthleteDbList.Count; count++)
                    {
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 img-responsive">
                            <video style="height:250px; width:250px" controls="controls">
                                <source src="@Html.DisplayFor(vidmod => vidmod.AthleteDbList[count].AthleteVideo)" type="video/mp4" />
                            </video>
                            <br />
                            <strong>GroupShow_Candyland</strong>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

This should resolve your issues.

Comment: Chetan!!! Happiness runs through my veins! Thank you so much! Worked perfectly. I don't program much, and moving from webforms to mvc is a learning curve which I am enjoying! Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad that I could help to resolve your issue... Happy coding :)